# Chaves dinâmicas opcionais TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Estou tentando criar uma interface com **chaves dinâmicas**:

```
type Keys = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';

interface MyInterface {
  [key: Keys]: string;
}
```

Fazendo isso, recebo o seguinte erro:

> An index signature parameter type cannot be a union type. Consider using a mapped object type instead.

Utilizando outra sintaxe, consigo um resultado que funciona, porém não da maneira que preciso:

```
type Keys = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';

type MyInterface = {
  [key in Keys]: string;
};
```

Dessa última forma, consigo utilizar esta tipagem em um objeto, porém o TS solicita o preenchimento dos valores de todas as `Keys`, no caso `a`, `b` e `c`:

```
// Objetivo:
// Erro: Type '{ a: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'MyInterface': b, c
const myObject: MyInterface = {
  a: 'OK',
};

// Sem erros:
const myObject: MyInterface = {
  a: 'OK',
  b: 'OK',
  c: 'OK',
};
```

Teria alguma maneira de tornar as **chaves opcionais**?

Obs: Não estou utilizando `[key: string]: string` pois quero que o "*intellisense*" mostre os campos disponíveis para preenchimento.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode declarar as propriedades opcionais usando o sinal de interrogação:

```
type Keys = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';

type MyInterface = {
  [key in Keys]?: string;
};
```

Uma outra opção é utilizar o tipo embutido `Partial<T>`, que torna todas as propriedades do tipo T opcionais:

```
type Keys = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';

type MyInterface = Partial<{
  [key in Keys]: string;
}>;
```